# How to change the display format of the input type='datetime-local' in HTML5?

Tags: html, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I have implemented a an input of type `datetime-local` which works well.

The problem is that most of the users of the app use the format `dd/mm/yyyy --:-- --` while datetime-local displays the date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --` which is causing more confusion than improving on the ease of use of the app.

I have tried to research and the only straight forward answer was a comment stating *'It's impossible'*

The only solution which works is to remove the type `datetime-local` and use a third party library or the pattern attribute of the input tag.

Even though this approach works was still hoping that the format for input of type `datetime-local` can be changed.

Comment: It uses the user's configured locale - so for me it would be `dd/mm/yyyy --:--` with a 24-hour time format. That's the whole point of the HTML5 form elements, it provides locale-awareness for free.